# Jmeter : While Controller. issue with the loop fetching the values from the CSV file(Having 2 columns)

Tags: jmeter

The Jmeter scripts with the while controller works fine for one user.

The CSV file has two columns:
FirstName   LastName
UserName1   Test1
UserName2   Test2
UserName3   Test3

when the tests are executed with the CSV file(with the iteration),
Iteration 1 : while controller will be executed : FirstName(UserName1) and LastName(Test1) updated correctly. Passed
Iteration 2 : while controller will be executed : FirstName(UserName2) and LastName(Test3) updated correctly. Fail.
Iteration 3 : while controller will be executed : FirstName(UserName3) and LastName(Test3) updated correctly. Fail.

Not sure why the the LastName is getting updated to Test3.
Appreciate, any response in this regard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given this stanza:

> The Jmeter scripts with the while controller works fine for one user.

my expectation is that you need to do something with [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) setting of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Default "Sharing Mode" of `All threads` means that each thread (virtual user) reads next line from the file on each iteration. If this behaviour doesn't fit your needs you need to amend it according to your expectations.

Unfortunately from your question it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, going forward please describe expected and actual result, show us While Controller's condition and [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the CSV file for each user/iteration, [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), etc. in other words: [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Default "Sharing Mode" is set to All threads.

FirstName LastName 
UserName1  Test1
UserName2 Test2
UserName3 Test3

The expectation here is, 
Iteration 1 : FirstName(UserName1) and LastName(Test1)
Iteration 2 : FirstName(UserName2) and LastName(Test2) 
Iteration 3 : FirstName(UserName3) and LastName(Test3)

While the Actual is:
Iteration 1 : FirstName(UserName1) and LastName(Test1)
Iteration 2 : FirstName(UserName2) and LastName(Test3) 
Iteration 3 : FirstName(UserName3) and LastName(Test3)

Thanks,
Krishna